# Astro pass varaiable for background image

Tags: javascript, background, astrojs

I want to pass an image url to a local style.

```
---
let backgroundUrl = '../assets/images/header-startseite.webp'
---

<Header backgroundUrl={backgroundUrl}/>
```

in the Header component:

```
export interface Props {

    backgroundUrl: string
}

const {backgroundUrl} = Astro.props

<style define:vars={{ backgroundUrl }}>
  .header {
    background-image: url('var(--backgroundUrl)');
  }
</style>
```

But that is not working..I use Astro 3.5
Help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would need to put url into the variable e.g.:

```
let backgroundUrl = 'url(../assets/images/header-startseite.webp)'

...

background-image: var(--backgroundUrl);
```

But it seems this won't work for images in `src` or `assets` by default.

A few ways I think:

1. Import the image and use `src` in the CSS variable.

```
---
import backgroundUrl from "../assets/images/header-startseite.webp";
---

<Header backgroundUrl={`url(${backgroundUrl.src})`} />
```

Header component:

```css
<style define:vars={{ backgroundUrl }}>  
  .header {  
    background-image: var(--backgroundUrl);  
  }  
</style>
```

2. Move these background images to the `public` folder and reference them that way:

```
let backgroundUrl = 'url(/images/header-startseite.webp)' // public/images/*

// Header component like above
```

Comment: Alex, thanks a lot.. No2. is working.  Background images and url seems to be tricky in all systems..

Comment: Great - feel free to mark it as answered.